# Simple example of a custom .net installer using the path of the installed app

Tags: .net, installation

I simply want to create a custom installer to run code after installation which requires the path of the installed application.

I read about [how to create a custom installer](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/0df20605-b457-42d6-b63c-341a3824474a.htm) and [Custom Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368066%28VS.85%29.aspx), as well as what [properties are available in the installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but I don't quite get how to access those properties from inside the custom installer code. (Don't even get me started on the complexity of [Windows Installer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185688%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).)

The best answer would be full code for a custom installer using the app path. This is what I've got so far:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Hawk
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class Installer : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public Installer()
        {

        }

        public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            base.Install(stateSaver);

            try
            {
                //TODO Find out installer path
                string path = (string)stateSaver["TARGETDIR"]; // Is this correct?
                // Environment.CurrentDirectory; // What is this value?
                MyCustomCode.Initialize(path);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // message box to show error
                this.Rollback(stateSaver);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess I've got to do everything myself (sigh) ;-)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;

namespace Hawk
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class Installer : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            base.Install(stateSaver);
            try
            {
                string assemblyPath = this.Context.Parameters["assemblypath"];
                // e.g. C:\Program Files\[MANUFACTURER]\[PROGRAM]\[CUSTOM_INSTALLER].dll
                MyCustomCode.Initialize(assemblyPath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO message box to show error
                this.Rollback(stateSaver);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to take a backup of the existing config files in the specified path, while installing the build?